# How can i replace a file in Onedrive USING THE Graph Api?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I have a fie that already exists in a Onedrive directory , filename is TestFile.txt

If i try to move a file with the same name to that directory it gives the error

```
    {"error":{"code":"nameAlreadyExists","message":"Name already exists",
```

I am copying the file to the destination folder as follows

I setup a Patch request to th endpoint  /me/drive/items/{Id}

set the body  and send the request.

```
        var filebody = new { parentReference = new { id = folderDestId }, name = fileName };
        request.AddJsonBody(filebody);
        var response = client.Execute(request);
```

But the file is not moved to the new locaion and it doesnt replace the existing file there.

Do i need to delete the file first and then move , or is there something the body I can send to make it automatically replace the file ?

Answer (score 0):

When uploading your file, there is an instance attribute called "[conflictBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-beta)" that you can set to "replace" to achieve that. Note that this is an instance attribute and should be included in the URL instead of the request body.